# GET doesn't get me the new data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, superagent

I don't really get why my component doesn't render its changes.

```
toggle() {
    var url = rest.appointments + "/appointments";
    Request.get(url).then((response) => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        appointments: response.body.map(a => Object.assign({}, a, { end: new Date(a.end), start: new Date(a.start) })),
        modal: !prevState.modal
      }));
    });
  }
```

The `toggle()` method is called when I clicked a button for creating a new appointment. Before I called this function, an appointment was created by the following method:
(I removed irrelevant lines)

```
saveAppointment() {
    var url = rest.appointments + "/appointment";
    Request.post(url)
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .send('{"end":"' + end + '","start":"' + start + '" ,"title":"' + this.state.title + '","allDay":"false"}')
    .end(function(err, res) {
        properties.toggle();
    });
  }
```

So `properties.toggle()`will call the method `toggle()` which is in the father component. When I create the first appointment, the component doesn't render. The GET call doesn't get me the newly created appointment from `saveAppointment()`.

However, if I call `saveAppointment()` again, the previously appointment is shown and the new one. So always the first one is not in the response of the first `GET`call.

What do I need to change that I get the new data in the `GET` call?

EDIT: I can sum it up by this question: How can I firstly make a POST and then a GET without messing up my GET results?

EDIT2: I just saw that sometimes it even works when I try it for the first time. I can't see why but it seems like it works when I wait a little bit before I create a new appointment.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is happening because of cache. Check your Network tab in a console. If response code is `304 (Not modified)` then browser used cached response. To avoid this you can use [cache-control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) HTTP header or add some random get parameter to your request like `?hash=[any-random-hash]`

Comment: I get a `200` response from my GET call. And a `201` from my `POST`.